# Using ThreadExceptionEventHandler: determine which thread caused the exception

Tags: .net, exception, thread-exceptions

Using the Application.ThreadExceptionEventHandler, is it possible to determine which thread caused the exception (the thread id)?

The same question applies to using the AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionEventHandler to catch non-UI thread exceptions.

If the answer is no, is there any other way to determine which thread raised the unhandled exception in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked, but I'd expect the handler to be executed in the thread which threw the exception - in which case `Thread.CurrentThread` would be what you want. I can't see how it would make much sense for the handler to be executed in any *other* thread.

Comment: Once again, you are correct :)  I ran a test and it proved your point